# ChessBase Tactics Database

Tags: software, tactics, chessbase

I was sent a database of over 3000 mate-in-2 puzzles; however, most of them (almost 2200 of them) only have the first move provided as a solution.  I am hoping that I will not have to go back and add the variations for the second move manually.  Is there a way to have ChessBase add the rest of the analysis?  I was hoping the Tactical Analysis would do this, but it just checks the first move and says "yep, it is the best one" without providing the variations.

Comment: Are you talking about mate-in-two normal positions, or composed mates that may have four or five different lines?

Comment: Some have many possible legal moves for the second player, but all are mate in 2.  It would be great if it would provide all the variations, but even if it could just provide a main line, that would be helpful.  It is tedious to go game-by-game in the database and add the rest of the variation.  All of the pieces are on normal squares (no composed positions with things like 20 pawns or pawns on the first rank).

Comment: I'm confused on how you are intend to use these puzzles. I suppose you are trying to improve your tactics? Then why do you need to have the solutions? If you can't find the mate, just start the engine.

Comment: @Msiipola That is beyond the scope of the question, but to answer your question anyway:  I'm loading them into a private Chessable course, and I do not want to practice just finding the first move in a mating sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The Deep Analysis option does this, however, it takes forever, and you have to do each game/problem one at a time. Sorry to say, that it probably is not worth it, but it does add in most, if not all, the subvariations. Sorry, I do not have better news, but I do not think there is an easy way for you.

This is just for reference on how to use ChessBase Tactical Analysis on a large number of games, but here is that.

First, open the database. I am not sure how well this will work with 3000 games, so you may have to break them up by 100's, but you can test that yourself.

Now, once the database is open, click on the first game you want, and hold the Shift key down while selecting the last game you want. That should highlight many games.

Right click on them, and select "Tactical Analysis". Once the box comes up, set the following: Time for 1 second, Coarse, Store Evaluations, and deselect "Erase old annotations" and training. "Replace" should be selected. Replace saves the new analysis.

Comment: This is what I had tried before.  The problem with this is that it does not complete the tactic.  It will label it (e.g. Decoy, Zugzwang, etc), but it does not add the remaining moves.

Comment: I realized after I posted what the problem was. I did not delete it since that process for using TA on a large scale might be helpful to someone. I am still looking for an answer. that solves your problem.